# How to show month max and min in D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am new to D3 and need to design a heatmap using D3. I had the data for 20 years and required to show the max and min for every month. The question is different month has different days and for February there is 28 days or 29 days. Can anybody help me?

Sorry for my unclear description.This is the part of the data.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoH1D.png) I need to use the max and min value of each month to draw a heatmap. The data is from 1997-01-01 to 2007-12-31.

Comment: Hello jrqwqa, and welcome to Stack Overflow! As it stands, it's a little bit unclear what you're asking. Could you add any code you've been using up until now and clarify what exactly the intended and actual output of that code is? Thanks!

Comment: You should look at the d3 documentation. Specifically look at d3.max() and d3.min() at the following link: https://github.com/d3/d3-array

Comment: unrelated to question: can you share the data? i am curious.

Comment: @alt255 That's not unrelated: actually, that's a fundamental, missing part of the question (hence it is off-topic, the close vote is mine).

Answer (score -1):

You can sort this out using `underscorejs` and `d3.extent`.

For Example your list is like,

```
data = [{
    month: 1,
    value: 10
}, {
    month: 1,
    value: 20
}, {
    month: 2,
    value: 30
}, {
    month: 2,
    value: 40
}];
```

You `underscore` `groupBy` method like,

```
result = _.groupBy(data, 'month');
```

Your result will be,

```
result = {
    1: [{
        month: 1,
        value: 10
    }, {
        month: 1,
        value: 20
    }],
    2: [{
        month: 2,
        value: 30
    }, {
        month: 2,
        value: 40
    }]
};
```

Then you can plot max and min values using `d3.extent`.